# Can the new Skylanders SWAP Force figures be used on the Spyro's Adventure portal?

Tags: skylanders, skylanders-swap-force

We have the older portal from Spyro's Adventure.  Can the new Skylanders: SWAP Force
figures be used on this portal?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it looks like the answer is no.  From [Activision Support](http://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Skylanders-SWAP-Force-Portal-Compatibility/?l=en_US&c=Game_Title%3ASkylanders_Giants&fs=Search&pn=1):

> However, you cannot use the Portal of Power from previous games with Skylanders SWAP Force.